# "Tor Profile" folder in Brave Browser cache

Tags: linux, web-browser

I am using Brave Browser `Version 1.0.0 Chromium: 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on Ubuntu 18.04. The browser has an option,  [open new private window with Tor](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018121491-What-is-a-Private-Window-with-Tor-) . When looking into cache files today, I found a folder named "Tor Profile", and then subdirectories "Cache" and "Code Cache". They further have some subdirectories which finally have binary files, 'index' and 'the-real-index'.
I'm not sure about how the browsers function and whether this is shady or not, but why are these files even present on the system if they are related to what I browsed in that mode?

Note that no windows of that mode are active.

Comment: Can you post where you found this file? The directory it was in?

Comment: This is the path
 /home/my_username/.cache/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Tor Profile

Answer (score 5):

Brave developer here.  We do not try to conceal *whether* you have used Tor or not -- that would be a little difficult.  We do, however, avoid storing your private browsing history.  If you find evidence of your private browsing history stored there, please let us know or file a bug.

You appear to be using a slightly older version of Brave (1.0.0) from before we changed how private windows with Tor work, which fixed a number of bugs (including at least one possible leak to disk).  If you update Brave, the corresponding directory will be at `.../Default/session_profiles/Tor Profile` instead of `.../Tor Profile`.  There shouldn't be any private browsing history there -- but if you find any, we'd like to hear about it!

Comment: I get what you're trying to say, but I don't think it answers the question as such. What is that needs to be stored? even after the person closes the tor window?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked into this.

It is very uncool this file exists .

When the file in BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Tor Profile is deleted.

It is re-generated after using the Tor feature with the browser again .

In the file ending in a _2 I could see today's date was logged - Tue, 21 Jan 2020 -----(edited out)  GMT

Additionally, I was able to look at some code in the file (that I opened as a text file.)

Some of the non-encrypted code include some public keys  that look to be pointing back to - ads-serve.brave.com/v1/catalog

My best guess for the reason for this file is to keep track of the BAT ( basic attention token ) or to still serve you advertisements somehow when you are using Tor. Another possibility could be you are routed through their servers before being routed through the Tor network.